# Compiling razor files slow when many references

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, iis-express, csc

After building my (large) MVC solution, it takes approximately 30 - 60 seconds for the page to show up in the browser (without the debugger attached). Using procmon, I have found the what is taking up the majority of the time is compiling each separate razor file. When the c# compiler is called, all of the project references are passed to it, for example:

```
csc.exe /t:library /utf8output /R:"ReferenceOne.dll" /R:"ReferenceTwo.dll" /out:"App_Web_4ggvz4di.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /w:4 /nowarn /warnaserror- "\App_Web_4ggvz4di.0.cs" "App_Web_4ggvz4di.1.cs"
```

However, it uses all of my project references (well over 300 in total), which results in a compile time of approximtely 4 seconds per razor file. If I manually change this command to have only the few references that are needed (about 10), then it takes 0.1 seconds to compile.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to improve this performance? Particularly how to explicitly tell the razor compiler which references are needed.

Comment: did you get any answers to this inquiry?  We are noticing some slow downs and think it may be related to this type of issue but have not narrowed it down exactly.